# ReferenceError: xxxx is not defined...assigning php variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have url mapped as:

```
xxx/app/reset.php?token=fc832c73b6695a782cb1040b48a1ac2e6c33aaf2&action=reset
```

I am assigning it as:

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
$token_ = "_".$token;
```

and storing in javascript variable as:

```
var token = String(<?php echo $token_; ?>);
```

But when I try to console log, it shows error as:

```
ReferenceError: _fc832c73b6695a782cb1040b48a1ac2e6c33aaf2 is not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Wrap the string in quote `var token = String('<?php echo $token_; ?>');` or  use `var token = '<?php echo $token_; ?>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace bellow line:

```
 var token = String(<?php echo $token_; ?>);
```

With

```
 var token = '<?php echo $token_; ?>';
```

Comment: Give some reasoning behind your answer.

Comment: I think the code with change is quite self explanatory, I just add comma to make it string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var token = String('<?php echo $token_; ?>');
```

Though the `'<?php echo $token_; ?>'` will be a string always, so you don't need to change its data type.